# Is there a way to make a specific color (white) in an image transparent for a webpage?

Tags: html, css, image, transparency, transparent

I want to be able to take my kingdom of loathing signature that has this code:

```
<a href="http://www.kingdomofloathing.com"><img src="http://sigs.kingdomofloathing.com/player_2192849/mode_bigsig/l1_clan/l2_clantitle/s1_level/s2_class/playerfeed_2192849_bigsig.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

I want to take the white background of the image and make it transparent. The reason why I can't do this in an image editor is because these signatures update every once in awhile according to what you have been doing in the game.

Comment: There might be a CSS3 filter for this, but even then, very few browsers will understand it.

Comment: This is not currently possible using only HTML & CSS.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to really understand what he/she is asking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

**The simple answer is that you can't do this with CSS and HTML**.

Adding transparency to the element with CSS like Frank Tudor stated (*via opacity*) will affect the entire image.

So really you have three options:

1. Edit the image using design software like Photoshop, removing the
   white bg and saving it out as a trans gif or png.
2. Utilize CSS opacity, but this will make the entire object transparent. If you're okay with that then this is probably the easiest solution.
3. Use a scripting language. As others stated you can *technically* edit images using certain scripting languages like PHP. This will be the most time-consuming/technical way to perform this task (depending on your coding skills).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Is there a program that can record what a web browser is clicking on and then when you stop the recorder, it converts the sequence into javascript code. Because if there was I could just make a script that enters the image's url into www.online-image-editor.com and then edits out the white background.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You can use web inspector to track what the browser is doing. But I don't even know if you have control over where this image is being stored or not, because I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are being updated, then it's up to whatever code you are using to dynamically create those images.  You should certainly be able to use transparency when creating the images, regardless of how they are made.

I recommend PNG rather than GIF, but either would work.

Post the code of however you generate the signature images, and someone can help you update it to use a transparent background.

Comment: I don't know the code for generating them... the people who made the Kingdom of Loathing made the signature generator.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that wasn't your own.  Without going to the original creators, you can't get the effect you desire.  Even if you were to load this image and edit it, you'd find that simply replacing white with transparent would not be good enough, because they use antialiasing (shades of gray pixels).  You would be left with ugly little bits of greyish white around the text.

Comment: Also, the pen color is black in those images, so if you made the background transparent, you'd have to be very careful of where you placed the image.  On a dark background, the text might be unreadable.  Your best bet is to make a request to the Kingdom of Loathing authors to offer the signature images in other color schemes.  Since they are appear to be all about black on white, I doubt it will happen, but you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are advanced manipulation functions javascript in one case I remember opacity being used for transparency and in most server-side programming languages you can find image functions.

The problem you face (without an image editor) is that transparency is parameter of the image as it is saved out (and some image types look better than others when it comes to transparency).

You could try this...

Try adding an ID or Class to your IMG tag and this bit of code.

```
#IDgifThing {
  opacity: 0.5;  /* 50% transparent */
}
```

I have not tested it, but I hope it helps you or at least puts your mind in the right direction.